# Query with lateral join is returning a value with parenthesis. How to remove it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, lateral-join

I'm using Postgres for a chat app. There I have two tables, one with the conversation ids and participants, and another table with the messages.

I'm running the following query to get all the conversations for a user, and I use a lateral join to include the last message on the results:

```
select c.id, c.title, c.members, max(m.created_at) delivered_at, last_message
from conversations c
join messages m on c.id = m.conversation_id
left join lateral (select message from messages m where c.id = m.conversation_id order by created_at desc limit 1) last_message on true 
where array[4] <@ c.members 
group by c.id, last_message
order by delivered_at desc
```

which works, but the message is returned as `(message)` and not `message`

and I don't know why, really. Is there anyting I can do so I don't have to replace the parenthesis as an additional step?

Comment: you mean the column name or the values? please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of table name or alias you need to mention column name in select list:

```
select c.id, c.title, c.members, max(m.created_at) delivered_at, last_message
from conversations c
join messages m on c.id = m.conversation_id
left join lateral (select message from messages m where c.id = m.conversation_id order by created_at desc limit 1) as t(last_message) on true 
where array[4] <@ c.members 
group by c.id, last_message
order by delivered_at desc
```

Explanation:

In PostgreSQL, a reference to a table name (or alias) in a query is effectively a reference to the composite value of the table's current row. For example, if we had a table inventory_item as shown above, we could write:

```
SELECT c FROM inventory_item c;
```

This query produces a single composite-valued column, so we might get output like:

```
      c
------------------------
 ("fuzzy dice",42,1.99)

(1 row)
```

Note however that simple names are matched to column names before table names, so this example works only because there is no column named c in the query's tables.

The ordinary qualified-column-name syntax table_name.column_name can be understood as applying field selection to the composite value of the table's current row. (For efficiency reasons, it's not actually implemented that way.)

When we write

```
SELECT c.* FROM inventory_item c;
```

then, according to the SQL standard, we should get the contents of the table expanded into separate columns:

| name | supplier_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fuzzy dice | 42 | 1.99 |

```
(1 row)
```

as if the query were

```
SELECT c.name, c.supplier_id, c.price FROM inventory_item c;
```

Quoted from below link:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE

Comment: This is brilliant, and also correct.  TLDR: Use the item and not the table when doing your selec.